# JS Api redirecting to 404 after successful payment

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am trying to make an application. When I click a button this function below start working. It is generating a page and after choosing an option it is redirecting to payment section. Payment is working. but after payment is done it is showing error 404 not found page as json. I do want to link this like thank you for paying page but I don't know how can I do this. Also I can see api only on swagger ( I don't have original files). What should I do?

```
function getEx()
{

let sessionKey = null;
let transactionLink= null;

var response = Response.redirect("http://www.google.com", 302);
fetch('apikeyishere...',{
method: 'POST',
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
body: JSON.stringify({
  amount: 800,
    currency: "EUR",
    description: "donation"
})
}).then(res => {return res.json()
})

.then( data => {transactionLink = data.transaction_link; console.log(data); window.location = transactionLink; })

}
</script>
```

transaction link is as it says payment page. It is working, payment is done but return, it is error. When I check from account I can see its paid as well.

Comment: What is the URL in the browser that shows the 404?

Comment: @aksappy https://api.raisedforyou.com it is exactly redirecting here and this is the error I am getting. how can I change this address?

Comment: In your payment gateway API, do you have a callback url option?

Comment: @aksappy well I didn't design the api. I am just using. Another guy designed it for this project. So after successful payment it leads this page. So I guess no callback url. Is it my side problem or his side? I can see the api from swagger as well. How can I set up callback url so I can led the website like thank you page after payment?

Comment: Usually, payment gateways have callback urls that will redirect based on the payment completion. It looks like the returned link/url is the reason for 404 and not your code.

Comment: @aksappy can I fix by coding? adding something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202595/discussion-between-aksappy-and-ozkan-adar).